# How to add highcharts-more.src.js to an angular2 project?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, angular

I'm mapping highcharts-more to the system variable:

```
'highcharts-more': 'node_modules/highcharts/highcharts-more.src.js'
```

However it constantly gives me an error of:

```
Error in dev/process/templates/detail.template.html:40:33
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Error: Highcharts error #17: www.highcharts.com/errors/17
```

Does anyone has an idea how I could fix it so I could use boxplot type of chart?

Answer (score 3):

## systemjs.config.js

```
var  map = {
   ...
   'angular2-highcharts':        'node_modules/angular2-highcharts',
   'highcharts/highstock.src':   'node_modules/highcharts/highstock.js',
   'highcharts/highcharts-more.js': 'node_modules/highcharts/highcharts-more.js',
   ...
}
```

## my.component.ts

```
import {CHART_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2-highcharts';
import {Highcharts} from 'angular2-highcharts';


require('highcharts/highcharts-more.js')(Highcharts);


@Component({
   ...
})
export class CompareMeasureComponent implements OnInit {
   ...
}
```

it's work :)

Answer (score 1):

I have spent quite some time on this one. I finally found an answer in https://github.com/gevgeny/angular2-highcharts/issues/21

While I'm using angular2-highcharts package, there has to be a line of requirement included into Highcharts.js file.

```
require('../../highcharts/highcharts-more.js')(Highcharts);
```

This solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```js
declare var require: any;
var Highcharts = require('highcharts');
require('highcharts/highcharts-more.js')(Highcharts);
export { Highcharts };
```

Answer (score 0):

Highcharts **#17** error means, your mapping did not work and `highcharts-more.js` did not load correctly. Try this;

```
'highcharts-more': 'http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js'
```

Comment: Are you also mapping `jquery`, `highcharts` and `highcharts-more` with this order?

Comment: jquery I added before System configs. highcharts I put inside the mapping.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem and resolved using below line of code in my component class:

```
const Highcharts = require('highcharts');
require('highcharts/highcharts-more')(Highcharts);
```

and below line of code in SystemJs.Config.js

```
'highcharts/highcharts-more': "npm:highcharts/highcharts-more.js"
```